# Clustering a sequence of numbers

Tags: cluster-analysis, sequence

I have a small clustering problem- I have this sequence:

349, 1496, 348, 1497, 347, 1503, 1502, 1495, 353, 352, 351, 1501, 354, 1504, 1498, 1500

And I want to detect that there are two clusters- one around 350 and other around 1500. Is there any straightforward solution to this? So far I tried rounding to nearest 100, e.g. `int(round(x1 / 100.0)) * 100`, which does not always work because the numbers may vary; and the other is using silhouette method which seems too much for this small problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the data.

Split at the largest Gap.